# Used jQuery plugin for the date picker (element in form) but the date picker calendar isn't quite visible

Tags: html, jquery

The date picker label and input are in the body of a form

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          var date_input = $('input[name="date"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
          var container = $('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
          var options = {
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            container: container,
            todayHighlight: true,
            autoclose: true,
          };
          date_input.datepicker(options);
        })
    </script>
```

datepicker options are in a form

Comment: When you say "isn't quite visible" do you mean the datepicker is not displaying when you click the ```input[name="date"]``` control?

Answer (score -1):

I've had this problem before try add `position:relative` to the element that contains the datepicker otherwise it will not be absolutely positioned relative to it's container

```
<form style="position:relative">
   <input type="text" name='date'>
</form>
```

Comment: While it may answer the question, as it is now it is more a comment. I would suggest adding more detail (such as code chunks) or descriptions to illustrate ***why*** this is the answer to the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28329721)

Comment: "While it may answer the question this does not provide an answer to the question" Clear as mud.